# Apache freezing, How to detect which virtual host is getting hit?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, memory, timeout

I have a production server that in the last 24 hours has been hard rebooted 4 times due to freezes. Ping is fine but all other services time-out (Apache, SSHd, etc). I have now diagnosed it to Apache running out of memory due to an exorbitant amount of child processes forking suddenly within seconds of starting Apache. Stopping Apache just after rebooting keeps the server stable again.

My two questions are:

1. Is there a way to detect which of the vhosts is being suddenly hammered without looking into each vhost's access log one by one?
2. Is there a way to quickly enable/disable vhosts without commenting (#) them all out in httpd.conf?

A few system details:

Fedora 10, x86_64, PHP 5, Apache 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting up a status page using [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html). If you can get in after starting up your server you should see a page [like this](http://www.apache.org/server-status) which shows each connection with its corresponding vhost, and URL.

If your site is so heavily flooded that you can't get in, try running `netstat -nt | grep :80` or `lsof -ni tcp:80` to see if one or two addresses are flooding your site and apply iptables accordingly.

Comment: Good point about the mod_status. The two other suggestions worked out well too. Another way I approached it was like this tail -f /home/*/logs/access_log.

Answer (score 2):

1) I often use **lsof** to see what files/directories apache has open during time of high load. So for instance (on debian/ubuntu) you could run:

```
lsof -u www-data
```

and then to get something more useful, only search for open files in the correct location (e.g. /home) and then exclude the log files which should always be open.

```
lsof -u www-data | grep /home | grep -v *.log
```

You may have to run this a few times to get an idea of what is running often.

2) If your running debian/ubuntu you can use the **a2ensite** and **a2dissite** to automatically add and remove vhosts from your apache setup.

Comment: Thx Coops, I tried lsof but no files appear listed (apart from log files) when grepping only /home (where the vhosts are located).

I have updated the initial question with system details.

Comment: @mr-euro it's a bit strange that no files appearing! Either your not looking for the right entries, or they are happening to quickly (which is strange for an over loaded box). What about doing the lsof command combined with watch, so for instance:
     watch -n 0.5 'lsof...'
This will run the lsof command for you every half second.

Comment: Shortening the timeframe did show something thanks.

Comment: This was such a lifesaver today! On a Plesk server you need to use `lsof -u www-data | grep httpdocs | grep -v *.log` because on a Apache Plesk shared server Apache has 100s of log files open, therefor the `httdocs`